# Backbonejs - where i put the calculations?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Where can I put some calculations for example for calculate  employee salary? Is necesary use external file or i can use model or collection or view?

Answer (score 2):

The model's properties represent the state of the data entity (Employee). Its methods are supposed  to change the state of the data entity. So the method of model `calculateSalary()` could be nice choice to operate with `salary` property (increase, decrease, calculate, etc.).

It's a common approach in OOP. When you have a class `Car` with the `speed = 0`, you could call its method `run()` to increase the `speed` (change the state). The same idea with the Employee and his/her `salary`.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Employee = Person.extend({
    defaults: {
        hoursWorked: 0,
        hourlyRate: 0,
        salary: 0
    },
    initialize: function() {
        Person.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.on('change:hoursWorked change:hourlyRate', this.calculateSalary);
        this.calculateSalary();
    },
    calculateSalary: function() {
        this.set('salary', this.get('hoursWorked') * this.get('hourlyRate'));
    }
});

var driver = new Employee({
    hoursWorked: 10,
    hourlyRate: 15
});

console.log(driver.get('salary')); // 150

driver.set('hourlyRate', 25);
console.log(driver.get('salary')); // 250

driver.set('hoursWorked', 20);
console.log(driver.get('salary')); // 500
```